# Do any compilers support the new C++17 structured bindings yet?

Tags: c++, compiler

The (probable) final feature-set for the C++17 ISO standard has been publicized, and [among these features is something called structured bindings](https://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/final-features-of-c17.html):

```
auto [a,b] = /* something like a tuple */;
```

Are there any compilers that implement this yet? It appears that GCC doesn't even include this feature in their [C++1z status table](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11) yet, and LLVM [lists it but does not yet support it](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) in any version.

Is there a compiler that implements this feature? Preferably I'd like something online e.g. via IDEONE or Wandbox; failing that I'd like something that will work on Debian Linux, and in the last resort I can use Windows.

Comment: (I'm not sure if this is *exactly* the right site for this question....)

Comment: I agree (+1); technically, this ***is*** the correct site, since the OP is asking for a software recommendaiton. In practise, he is more likely to get knowledgable answers on http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Mawg I am the OP, and the above comment is mine! I just like to express any uncertainty I have about the appropriateness of a question in advance of possibly being told I shouldn't have posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Clang nightlies now work for pairs and tuples, but not for custom structs.

Comment: This ought to have been a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

GCC 7.2 on Ubuntu 17.10 does with `-std=c++17`.